# Using AJAX to set variable in MYSQL Query

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

What I'm trying to do is to use the value from a form on page one to set one of the parameters of a SQL query on page 2.  Using AJAX, I'm able to send the value from the form to page 2 (SQL page), but obviously, there an issue with server vs. client-side programming to where the query has run before the execution of the function.  What is the solution to this, or is there a completely different/better way of going about this?

Page 2 (AjaxReceive.php) contains this

```
<?PHP
  $Table = $_GET['sort'];   
  if (empty($Table)) $Table = "Members";
 ?>

 <p class="tab">Number Results: 
   <?PHP
     $sql="SELECT * FROM $Table";
     $result=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);
     $records=mysqli_num_rows($result);
     echo($records);
   ?>
 </p>
```

Page 1 (AjaxSend.php) contains this

```
<form method="get" name="form" id="form" action="#result"> 
  <select id="sort" name="sort";>
    <option value="Members">Members</option>
    <option value="Taxa">Taxa</option>
  </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>     

<div id="result"></div>

 <script type ="text/javascript">
   function post()
    {
    var table = $('#sort'). val();
    
     $.post ('AjaxReceive.php',{sort:table,},
       function(data)
        {
        $('#result').html(data);
        });
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: try async/await with ajax. [Read more here](https://petetasker.com/using-async-await-jquerys-ajax)

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to call the `post` function you defined.